# How can I force a SQL GROUP BY ? Or choose to prefer one of the value available?

Tags: sql

I have two tables :

Table 1 (T1) :

| ID | AMOUNT | NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100$ | 456 |
| 2 | 22$ | 789 |

Table 2 (T2) :

| NUMBER | VALUE (string) |
| --- | --- |
| 456 | abc |
| 456 | def |
| 789 | ghi |

My Query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.ID, T1.AMOUNT, T2.VALUE
FROM T1 RIGHT JOIN T2 ON T1.NUMBER = T2.NUMBER
```

Result (that I don't want) :

| ID | AMOUNT | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100$ | abc |
| 1 | 100$ | def |
| 2 | 22$ | ghi |

If I try to GROUP BY ID, I will get an error.

I tried different JOIN methods and the RIGHT JOIN was the one with the best output (fewer lines in the result than the others).

I tried some other things that didn't worked out.

The goal would be to only have a distinct ID on my result.
It could be by choosing the first value of the two alphabetically or with an other method i dont know the possibilities but the most important thing to me is to have only one ID / AMOUNT per row and have whatever VALUE available because this value is less relevant in my later calculations but I still need it.

One of the possible wanted result :

| ID | AMOUNT | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100$ | abc |
| 2 | 22$ | ghi |

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Tagging multiple conflicting technologies makes your question unclear and thus *harder* to answer. It is also unlikely to get your question "more views" and likely to have the opposite effect, where only users who know *all* the RDBMS you have (mis)tagged will entertain the question; that is often a very small portion of the user base. Tag spam is far more likely to result in your question receiving downvotes and/or being closed as unclear. Please [edit] your question to retag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: @Larnu thank you for the information. This is my first post. Have you an idea why before you edited the post all the tables didn't appeared as they should have ? Now it is working but right after I posted, it didn't.

Comment: You didn't have a line break before the tables. As for why they work now, I edited the post to correct that (as well as removing you tag spam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an aggregate function to roll up the columns you are grouping by if you don't want duplicates:

```
SELECT T1.ID, SUM(T1.AMOUNT), MAX(T2.VALUE)
FROM T1
RIGHT JOIN T2 ON T1.NUMBER = T2.NUMBER
GROUP BY T1.ID
```

**Note to mods:** I am reposting my accepted answer since the original answer was removed in the ChatGPT witch hunt. In hindsight I can see how my choice of words ("Here's an example...") may have created an incorrect impression. Be assured that this answer was and is a product of my brain and not ChatGPT. If you disagree, let's talk about it instead of just deleting an accepted answer, which was confirmed to be a valid solution by the asker, no less.